# When Route is passed as Array its not working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

The following snippet works fine,

```
<Router history={history}>
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <Suspense fallback={<div className="loadingMessage">Loading...</div>}>
            <div className="home">
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/a" component={A} />
                    <Route path="/b" component={B} />
                    <Route path="/c" component={C} />
                    <Route path="/d" component={D} />
                    <Route path="/f" component={F} />
                    <Route path="/g" component={G} />
                    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
</Router>
```

But, when it is changed that way given below, Its redirecting to path "/". I am just rendering routes as an array. why it should change the default behaviour.

```
const routes = routesList.map((item, index) => {
    return <Route key={index} path={item.route} component={item.component}/>
})
return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <Suspense fallback={<div className="loadingMessage">Loading...</div>}>
            <div className="home">
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    {routes}
                    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </div>
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Router>
);
```

where routesList is an array of objects containing url and component as properties.

Comment: Does it correctly render your route if you remove the redirect ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour, nor can I find any reason it to behave like this in the `react-router` source code (assuming it *is* `react-router`). I suspect there's something wrong with the `routes` array itself. Can you share your `routesList` definition or any other relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you can change the quotes **" "** to `` and put your route between little quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and it works fine for me. Test it please and compare it with yours.

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,    
    Redirect
  } from "react-router-dom";


export const MainRouter = ({children}) => {    
    const routesList = [{route: '/a', component: A}, {route: '/b', component: B}]
    const routes = routesList.map((item, index) => {
        return <Route key={index} path={item.route} component={item.component}/>
    })
    return (
        <Router>

            <div className="home">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    {routes}
                    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </div>


</Router>
    );
};

export default MainRouter;
```

Actually don't know what is the problem in your code. Maybe if you send yours more complete it helps.